# Get Actionbar click event xamarin.android

Tags: android, mono, android-actionbar, xamarin

Im have added a back icon to the action bar,now when i click on that i need to go back to the activity that started it.Is there a actionbar click event which i can hook to and call the `this.finish` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to work the home button properly and capture it's action event. You must have to first enabled the home button by calling [setHomeButtonEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled%28boolean%29) for targeting android **API level 14 onwards**.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Now you've to override the **onOptionsItemSelected** method inside your activity to capture the home button action of actionbar and also "**Back**" key on some of the android devices.

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                     finish();    // this will dismiss the current activity 
                }
                return true;
        }
```